# Postgres: how can I create an FK reference on a partial index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

We want to maintain referential integrity between two tables, but we also want to soft delete records. SQL to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    deleted_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    uuid         UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_uuid ON table_a (uuid) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;

CREATE TABLE association (
    id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    deleted_at       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    table_a_uuid     UUID REFERENCES table_a (uuid) NOT NULL
);
```

The problem is, Postgres does not allow foreign key references to partial indexes, of which `association.table_a_uuid` is. Is there any way I can maintain referential integrity between these tables in PSQL, or do I have to do it in the application layer?

Edit: To add some extra context as to why we want to use `uuid` as the FK ref, soft-deleted records on `table_a` represent older "versions" of the record, but all "versions" have the same `uuid`. The referencing `association` table should "point" to the latest version of the `table_a` record.

Answer (score 4):

There is a rather kludgy way to do what you want.  The idea is a two-part index, one with the `uuid` and the second with the `id` -- but only for deleted records.  For the non-deleted, it has a constant value and `-1` is convenient.

They you can construct a foreign key reference to that:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    deleted_at   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    id_if_deleted  int generated always as (case when deleted_at is null then -1 else id end) stored,
    uuid         UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_uuid ON table_a (uuid, id_if_deleted) ;

CREATE TABLE association (
    id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
    deleted_at       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    const_neg_one    int generated always as (-1) stored,
    table_a_uuid     UUID,
    foreign key (table_a_uuid, const_neg_one) REFERENCES table_a (uuid, id_if_deleted )
);
```

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting idea. It could even been simplified to a `is_deleted` boolean field.

Comment: @ericso . . . That would not work because it would allow. only one deleted record.

Comment: it would work if you set it to null on deleted records instead of to true.

Comment: `is live` might be a better name than `is_deleted` however.  it also saves on storage as null columns use none.